# How to properly clear and add options to work with Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo

Hey all, recently I came across a problem. I am not able to add options to a select box with the code below nor clear them in IE. Is there something wrong with the below code?

```
        blockSelect.innerHTML = '<option></option>';
        for (var i in data.DATA) {
            console.log(data);
            var option = dojo.create('option', { value: data.DATA[i][0] }, blockSelect);
            option.label = data.DATA[i][0];
        }
```

I really have no idea why this isn't working in IE.

Thanks

Comment: For starters, JavaScript does not have block-level scoping. Every iteration of your `for` loop will overwrite the previous value of `option`. Could you post a bit more code?

Comment: it's not used outside of the block, so it doesn't matter

Comment: @Matt: There's no problem at all with that. Variable instantiation takes place before any statements are executed. The following two snippets are equivalent: `for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { var x = i; }` and `var x; for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { x = i; }`

Comment: @Tim: yes, I know. Both will end with `var x` existing outside of the `for` loop's scope, with value `2`. That's more-or-less what I meant about "overwriting" the previous value. But, the code snippet is incomplete so I was just guessing at the issue.

Comment: Yeah guys I knew about the scope. Anyways if you haven't seen the solution was setting my values using treetSelect.options[streetSelect.selectedIndex].value. IE does not like the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Never wrote dojo in my life, but here's an attempt. With a few pointers

```
blockSelect.innerHTML = '<option></option>';
console.log(data);
for (var i in data.DATA) {
  var item = data.DATA[i];
  dojo.create('option',
        {
           value: item[0],
           label: item[0], // do you mean to set the innerHTML?
           innerHTML: item[0]
        },
        blockSelect);
}
```

Comment: If this still doesn't work, try qw3n's comment by removing the line that sets the first option to an empty option

Answer (score 2):

Use the `options` property of the select list. You can clear it by setting the `length` property to 0, and you can add a new option by assigning a new `Option` object as the last element of the `options` collection:

```
var opts = blockSelect.options;
opts.length = 0;
for (var i in data.DATA) {
    console.log(data);
    opts[opts.length] = new Option(data.DATA[i][0], data.DATA[i][0]);
}
```

This works in all major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about how to answer your question using Dojo, but I suspect your problem may have to do with a long standing problem in IE using `innerHTML` and the `option` tag.  I think the solution is to append the option elements to the parent instead of trying to set the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is getting this same problem here is what was the problem:
For Internet Explorer I had to use streetSelect.options[streetSelect.selectedIndex].value for my content values instead of streetSelect.value. For some reason Internet Explorer does not read that.